# How to use Plotly with Zeppelin

Tags: python, apache-spark, plotly, apache-zeppelin

I've seen [zeppelin-plotly](https://github.com/beljun/zeppelin-plotly) but it seems too complicated. The other things that worries me is that it involves modifying zeppelin's `.war` file and I don't want to break things by error.

Is there another way to use Plotly with Zeppelin?

Answer (score 12):

Figured it out using the `%angular` interpreter feature. Here are the full steps to get it working

### 1: Install plotly (if you haven't)

```
%sh pip install plotly
```

You can also do this on the terminal if you have access to it

### 2: Define a plot function

```
def plot(plot_dic, height=500, width=500, **kwargs):
    kwargs['output_type'] = 'div'
    plot_str = plotly.offline.plot(plot_dic, **kwargs)
    print('%%angular <div style="height: %ipx; width: %spx"> %s </div>' % (height, width, plot_str))
```

This custom plot funtion uses the angular interpreter to plot html. It take the same parameters as `plotly.offline.plot` plus some extra parameters for the div's dimensions (I had bad results without these). Use it as you normally would use `plotly.offline.plot`.

#### Note

These plots are interactive! You don't need `iplot`, the `plot` function defined here works for 3D interactive plots as well.

## Full Example

```
%pyspark

import plotly
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout


def plot(plot_dic, height=500, width=500, **kwargs):
    kwargs['output_type'] = 'div'
    plot_str = plotly.offline.plot(plot_dic, **kwargs)
    print('%%angular <div style="height: %ipx; width: %spx"> %s </div>' % (height, width, plot_str))


plot({
    "data": [
        Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[4, 5, 3, 7])
    ],
    "layout": Layout(
        title="hello world"
    )
})
```